# Failed to pull private git repo using node alpine

Tags: node.js, git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to build a local docker image for my front-end application in Vue using `node:16.15.0-alpine` which fails because my `package.json` file has a private repo in it.

However, when I build image using `node:16.15.0` everything works fine although my docker image size shoots to `1.8GB`.

Below is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.15.0-alpine as develop-stage
# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install 

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    frontend:
        container_name: frontend-test
        image: frontend-test:latest
        build: 
            context:.
            dockerfile: ./dockerfile.dev
            target: 'develop-stage'
        networks:
            - test-app-network
        environment:
             - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: true
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
volumes:
  test-data:
    external: false

networks:
  test-app-network:
    external: false
```

My package.json file

```
...
depedencies: {
  private-repo: 'git+https://username:apppassword@bitbucket.org/myproject/myrepo.git'
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the `node:16.15.0` image has `git` installed, while the `node:16.15.0-alpine` image has not. Hence the git clone of the private repository will fail due to lack of the `git` command.

This can be fixed by installing the `git` package manually inside the `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:16.15.0-alpine as develop-stage

RUN apk add --no-cache git
...
```

This will add the `git` package to the image and therefore increase the image size (by about 13 MiB). If git will be needed later on in the image anyway, this may make sense. If git is only needed during the initial `npm install` this overhead can be avoided by combining `apk add`, `npm install` and `apk del` in a single `RUN` stanza:

```
FROM node:16.15.0-alpine as develop-stage
...

RUN apk add --no-cache git && npm install && apk del git
...
```